# Internet Explorer 7 error

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

http://jinoh.dk/vol2/

I am working on this website - portfolio for myself, but I can't click anything in IETester in IE7. Works fine in every other browser + IE8 and above, but not IE7.

Unfortunately many people still use this. The layout doesn't even work. Silly browser

Can anyone help me spot the error?

Comment: Extra: It's still just an alpha-version. So I know, there would be some coding errors and non-valid elements. :)

Comment: Just FYI, if you have IE9 installed, pressing F12 brings up a developer menu, which amongst it's many features is an option to switch the rendering engine to 7 or 8. I find its much more consistent than IE Tester.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know. Thank you! Rarely use the 9-browser :)  Edit: This made the buttons work. I'll never touch IETester again. Promise! Thank you, @Tieson T.

Comment: Another strange thing happened. The other "converted from old theme"-page at http://jinoh.dk/vol2/referencer.htm is working. But the Index.htm is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

It had something to do with a styleswitching script I had on the previous theme.

Thanks for the help to everyone.

Comment: Please elaborate so this will have some future value. what script exactly? Can you narrow it down to specific line or block of code that not working in IE7?

Comment: It was related to a javascript script. I think it had something to do with the name="" inside the <style>-tag.

Answer (score 1):

IE 7 has limited support on HTML5. There is no point to use HTML5 in IE 7 as HTML5 is released after IE 7.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, the main site works just fine in IE7 with HTML5. It's just www.jinoh.dk